# Gitbook PDF convertion error: ENOENT

Tags: pdf, gitbook, enoent

I used gitbook to write my thesis and now I need it converted to PDF. 
Looked at every instruction there is and got `gitbook pdf` command to work. 
Next day I was told to install gitbook 3.0 so i did by using `gitbook fetch latest`. 
From that point on the `gitbook pdf` command gave the error

> error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\some\path\to\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-\gitbook\ebook.css'

I checked to see if this file exists and it does, everytime I check the file the `tmp_<somegibberish>` changes but the file is always present.

Does anyone know what the problem is? 
Is there a solution? 
Is there any other way to convert gitbook projects to pdf?

Comment: Do you have any copies of your thesis uploaded to GitBook.com?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Just had to do a roll-back of the version and reïnstal the update

Answer (score 0):

~/.gitbook/versions/3.2.3/lib/output/website/copyPluginAssets.js file, then find all the concursive configuration items in this file (2 places in total), change the original value true to False.

confirm: false